# Nodejs myqsl errorno: -104

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a simple node server which accepts bookings. I use mysql for database and I frequently get an error message on production which restarts my node server (and causing issues with the booking system)

this is the error that I recieve

```
App 1800097 output: Error: read ECONNRESET
App 1800097 output:     at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
App 1800097 output: Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
App 1800097 output:     at Connection._handleProtocolError (/user/nodevenv/server/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
App 1800097 output:     at Protocol.emit (node:events:513:28)
App 1800097 output:     at Protocol._delegateError (/user/nodevenv/server/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
App 1800097 output:     at Protocol.handleNetworkError (/user/nodevenv/server/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:371:10)
App 1800097 output:     at Connection._handleNetworkError (/user/nodevenv/server/16/lib/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:418:18)
App 1800097 output:     at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
App 1800097 output:     at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
App 1800097 output:     at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
App 1800097 output:     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
App 1800097 output:   errno: -104,
App 1800097 output:   code: 'ECONNRESET',
App 1800097 output:   syscall: 'read',
App 1800097 output:   fatal: true
App 1800097 output: }
```

I cant really figure out what is causing this issue

thanks for the suggestsions

Comment: MySQL drops the connection after x seconds if there are no queries to resolve. A hacky way is to implement a custom `setInterval` timer which will execute a simple query `SELECT NOW()` after each minute or so. I had this problem before, and I found that this was the best solution for me.

Comment: Changing your nodejs app to use a MySQL connection pool, rather than just a connection, can mitigate this very common production problem.

Comment: thanks! I fixed it by using pools instead

Comment: Pools will definitely solve it. pool.query will allow you to get a connection, run a query and then automatically close it when finished. pool.getConnection will allow you to run multiple queries (i.e. in a transaction) using one connection, but it requires manual connection closing. Make sure you use the appropriate method, otherwise you could end up using all available connections and then crash.